# how to clear/release audio contact html5

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

is there any way to clear/release/remove audio context in html5?

I have gone through the below tutorials but could not find anything.

[Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`youraudiocontext.close();`

Simple enough?

After you close it, you can use the `then()` method to basically reset:

```
youraudiocontext.close().then(function() {
    // set things here //
});
```

> The close() method of the AudioContext Interface closes the audio context, releasing any system audio resources that it uses.
>
> Closed contexts cannot have new nodes created, but can decode audio data, create buffers, etc.
>
> This function does not automatically release all AudioContext-created objects, unless other references have been released as well; however, it will forcibly release any system audio resources that might prevent additional AudioContexts from being created and used, suspend the progression of audio time in the audio context, and stop processing audio data. The returned Promise resolves when all AudioContext-creation-blocking resources have been released. This method throws an INVALID_STATE_ERR exception if called on an OfflineAudioContext.

Comment: close() is undefined in ios7